# Is this Diophantine equation?

Tags: logarithms

How would I solve : 
$\log_a(b)=log_b(a)\}$
such that a and b is not equal to 1 and a is not equal to b.
Would Diophantine equation be the way to go for this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\log_a b=\frac{1}{\log_b a}$$ so the question is equivalent to 
$$(\log_a b)^2=1$$ so $a=b$ or $a=b^{-1}$.

Comment: While trying to solve the question I also found a = b by applying the properties of log. I followed and understand each of your steps, but I don't see why a = b^-1. I understand the a = b.

Comment: What if $\log_a b=-1$?

Answer (score 0):

Recall $\log_a(b)=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$. Your equation can be rewritten as $\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}=\frac{\ln a}{\ln b}$. You should be able to solve this now. Since this looks like a homework problem, I will not reveal more details.